# Carousel freezes when php file is inside a folder

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with a website and have the following situation:

The Bootstrap Carousel works fine when the file index.php in on the root, however, if I rename the same php file and move it into a folder, the carousel freezes.

Please inspect the url.  The one that works is http://webstudiopr.com/tertuleoPHP/index.php

The one that freezes is http://webstudiopr.com/tertuleoPHP/politica/politica-puerto-rico.php

Any idea on how to fix it?

Thanks

PJ

Answer (score 1):

Check all your relative paths -- assuming that you haven't moved all your files, for example:

Instead of:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Use:

```
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your head this tag:

```
<base href="http://webstudiopr.com/tertuleoPHP/">
```

It will set a base source for all absolute paths on the page - making `bootstrap.js` loaded from

```
http://webstudiopr.com/tertuleoPHP/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Instead of

```
http://webstudiopr.com/tertuleoPHP/politica/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

For more information about the `base` tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_base_href.asp

**On a side note**: Take a look at the source of your website - It's completely invalid (You put `meta` tags inside the body, and then closing the `head` after the opening `body` tag. Fix it too.